# Android declaring a textview in parent class xml and setting listener in child class

Tags: java, android, oop, button, onclick

Actually, I have 2 activities, `BaseActivity` and `ChildActivity`. `ChildActivity` is extending `BaseActivity`. I am declaring a `TextView` in Base class XML and I wanted to set listener of that `TextView` in `ChildActivity`.

I can directly call the functions defined in `BaseActivity` from `ChildActivity`, but how can I set `onClickListener` in child class?

Comment: you have to instantiate the textview first then you can call the setOnClickListener. Childclass also needs a reference for the textview, so it should have protected visibility at least if it's declared in the parent class.

Comment: create a public method in BaseActivity that sets click listener and call that method when you want to set click listener in child class.

Answer (score 3):

For that You can use

> interface

**create one interface**

```
interface Textview_InterFace
{
    Textview findTextview();

}
```

**Second step is to implement to your BaseActivity and also implement method**

And in Child Activity

```
public class childActivity extends BaseActivity
{
  Textview_Interface my_textview;
  Textview textview;
         @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  my_textview = (Textview_Interface) this;

  textview = my_textview.findTextview();

  //perform here your onClickListner     


}
```